# How to apply transformations to an object using the world matrix?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, matrix

I'm taking a computer graphics course. In one assignment I had to check if a matrix transformation maps points to another set of points

I thought that the best way to learn how this was to use Blender's Python API and try doing this.

These are my set of points

```
t0 = (−1, −1, −1)

t1 = (1, 1, −1)

t2 = (−1, 1, 1) 

t3 = (1, −1, 1)
```

The set of points I want to get mapped to are

```
u0 = (2, 2, −1)

u1 = (2, 2, 3)

u2 = (0, 0, 1)

u3 = (4, 0, 1)
```

and the transformation:

*Rotation about the z-axis by 45°, then scaling with sx =√2, sy =√2, sz = 1, then translation by (2, 1, −1), and then rotation about the x-axis by 90 degree.*

I created the two objects for the two set of objects. And I want to move the object t (with vertices t0,t1 ...) to the object u (with vertices u0, u1 ...)

```
#rotation around Z axis
rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(radians(90), 4, 'Z') 

# decompose world_matrix's components
orig_loc, orig_rot, orig_scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
#create the translation vector
translation =  mathutils.Vector((2,1,-1))
new_loc = orig_loc + translation
orig_loc_mat = Matrix.Translation(new_loc)
orig_rot_mat = orig_rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
orig_scale_mat = Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[0],4,(sqrt(2),0,0)) * 
Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[1],4,(0,1,0)) * 
Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[2],4(0,0,sqrt(2)))

obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat * rot_mat * orig_rot_mat * 
orig_scale_mat
```

This is not working, the object gets mapped to a wrong position.
The blue object is the object from t coordinates, the red from the u coordinates, the green one should be overlapping the red one.

[image]
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You need to apply the matrices in reverse order.

The code is given below. You can comment the last call (and the `createObjs` call if the objects are already created) and uncomment the commented `applyMatToVerts` calls one by one to see the effect of each matrix transformation (see gif above). 
The last `applyMatToVerts` call is equivalent of all the commented calls. It creates a single matrix and applies it to all the coordinates of the object. I am not using matrix world since the objects are at the origin. If they are not, the matrices need to be multiplied with `obj.matrix_world`.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians, sqrt
from mathutils import Matrix

def getMat(name, color):
    oldMat = bpy.data.materials.get(name)
    if(oldMat != None):
        bpy.data.materials.remove(oldMat)
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
    mat.diffuse_color = color
    return mat

def createObjFromCo(meshName, objName, coList, matName, matColor):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    verts = []
    for co in coList:
        verts.append(bm.verts.new(co))
    bm.faces.new(verts)
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(meshName)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(objName, mesh)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    mat = getMat(matName, matColor)
    obj.data.materials.append(mat)
    return obj

def applyMatToVerts(obj, mat):
    for vert in obj.data.vertices:
        vert.co = mat * vert.co

origObjName = 'origObj'
origCopyName = 'origCopyObj'
toMapObjName = 'toMapObj'

def createObjs():
    t = [(-1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1)]
    u = [(2, 2, -1), (2, 2, 3), (0, 0, 1), (4, 0, 1)]
    orange = (0.8, 0.2, 0.1)
    green = (0.2, 0.8, 0.2)
    blue = (0.2, 0.2, 0.8)
    origObj = createObjFromCo(origObjName+'_data', origObjName, t, '__obj1Mat__', orange)
    origCopy = createObjFromCo(origCopyName+'_data', origCopyName, t, '__objCopyMat__', blue)
    toMapObj = createObjFromCo(toMapObjName+'_data', toMapObjName, u, '__obj2Mat__',green)

createObjs()

origObj = bpy.data.objects['origObj']
origCopy = bpy.data.objects['origCopyObj']
toMapObj = bpy.data.objects['toMapObj']

rot_mat1 = Matrix.Rotation(radians(45), 4, 'Z') 
scale_mat1 = Matrix.Scale(sqrt(2), 4, (1,0,0))
scale_mat2 = Matrix.Scale(sqrt(2), 4, (0,1,0))
trans_mat = Matrix.Translation((2, 1, -1))
rot_mat2 = Matrix.Rotation(radians(90), 4, 'X') 

# ~ applyMatToVerts(origCopy, rot_mat1)
# ~ applyMatToVerts(origCopy, scale_mat1)
# ~ applyMatToVerts(origCopy, scale_mat2)
# ~ applyMatToVerts(origCopy, trans_mat)
# ~ applyMatToVerts(origCopy, rot_mat2)


applyMatToVerts(origCopy, rot_mat2 * trans_mat * scale_mat1 * scale_mat2 * rot_mat1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late, but as far as I remember, matrix multiplication in python requires '@' instead of '*'. For me, this worked instantly